# web.1 | bundler: command not found: puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a simple rails 4 app on my local machine and the Gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
ruby "2.2.2"
```

However, when I run

```
heroku local web
```

I get the following error

```
==> heroku local web
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | bundler: command not found: puma
web.1  | Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your `Procfile`. It looks like the web service is configured to use the `puma` web server, but the `puma` gem is not on your `Gemfile`.

Add `gem 'puma'` to your `Gemfile` or use another web server.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a really similar problem - My issue was that the 'puma' gem was called out in the "test" development section of my gem file. Moving this line of code, running bundle install and committing to git fixed it.